# Problems installing/importing Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, geos, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda (version 1.6.2) installed on my 64 bit machine. It comes with a great set of libraries, but I also need Basemap, part of matlibplot, but it is not included with the Anaconda install. I attempted to install Basemap and move the files in the Anacaonda\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits directory since it is part of the mpl_toolkits library. However when I attempt to run a script, I keep getting the errors:
"No module named _geoslib"
"Cannot import pyproj"

I  found the pyproj library. Do I need it? Where can I find geoslib? And how do I get Basemap to work?

Answer (score 10):

What you nees is to change your path first, by:

```
$ export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

and then,

```
$ conda install basemap
```

( I assumed you are in Linux)

source:http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html

Comment: The question mentions the directory "Anacaonda\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits".  With those backslashes, my first guess is the OP is using Windows.

Comment: aggree with this answer,you should install the package  within Anaconda

Answer (score 1):

If your on Windows try installing [Basemap from the Sourceforge executable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/), these should include GEOS and PROJ4 dependencies of Basemap.

Answer (score -1):

I believe all that is needed is to update matplotlib, I just had this problem and doing this worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```